# Do we can execute telnet from SshXCute by neoremind

Tags: java, telnet

We are using `SshXCute` java plugin by `neoremind` for connecting to a server through ssh. Now we need to connect to some other server/router by telnet. I searched a lot in Google to find any solution. All of them finally reaches to use `apache TelnetClient`. We want try our maximum to avoid include another jar in our application. Is there any posibility of using `SshXcute` for telnet connection?

Comment: Don't use SshXCute - the project only had 33 commits and looks abandoned. JSch is better.

Comment: I have mentioned clearly that i don't want to include one more jar into my application. If including a new jar is the only option, then I can go with apache commons TelnetClient. Anyway thanks for the suggession.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider using JSCAPE's [Secure iNet Factory](http://www.jscape.com/products/components/java/secure-inet-factory/). Documentation can be found [here](http://files.jscape.com/secureinetfactory/docs/html/). Secure iNet Factory supports both SSH sessions and Telnet within a single jar.

Comment: This is just another library right? I have mentioned clearly that i don't want to include one more jar into my application. I have already implemented Ssh with SshXCute. If including a new jar is the only option, then I can go with apache commons TelnetClient. Anyway thanks for the suggession. Please help me if there is any option to do telnet with SshXCute itself. :)

Comment: one more thing, JSCAPE's Secure iNet Factory is a paid one.

Comment: I don't think there is any option to do Telnet with SshXCute. You may have to use Apache Commons Telnet library. Yes JSCAPE library is a paid one but there is old adage 'you get what you pay for'.